# Siamese network: disable shared variable gradient back propagation

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am currently working on porting the siamese network of this paper: [Fully-Convolutional Siamese Networks for Object Tracking](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~luca/siamese-fc.html) from matlab to tensorflow code. I am having problems of kernels becoming NaN after 80k to 150k steps and have already tried some methods of preventing nan with gradient clipping and preventing a zero loss but I am still having some problems.

One of the things I am suspicious off is the back propagation, the siamese network I am trying to implement is unique in it's method of using one side of the networks output as a convolution "filter" for the other side. I have implemented this with some variable reshapes and a depth-wise convolution.

Since both sides of the network share the same weights using reuse=true in the variable scope, I think there is a problem with 2 gradients back propagating into one variable as can be seen in the screenshot.[Gradient descent calculation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Bt2.png)

What I want to try is to only back propagate one side of the gradient for updating the variables but still have both side share the same variables. In essence make a copy of the first variable that is updated whenever the first variable changes, but set the copy variable to trainable=False.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable gradient back propogation using this code:

```
second_siamese_no_backprop = tf.stop_gradient(second_siamese_output_layer)
```

I am not yet able to verify if this fixed the NaN issue.